# Using Spatie's Browsershot/Headless Chrome to capture extremely long screenshots

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-chrome-headless

I periodically run into scenarios where I need to use Spatie's [Browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) to capture extremely tall web pages. However, when I do this, the resultant screenshot repeats every 16,384 pixels. (You can see an example of the repetition here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1576)

This is a known limitation of Puppeteer (documented [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=770769&desc=2)). The recommended workaround for now seems to be taking several screenshots, and using `clip()` to offset the screenshot by increments of 16,384px. You can see an example of this approach using Node.js [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/230be28b067b521f0577206899db01f0ca7fc0d2/examples/screenshots-longpage.js).

Now, on the client side, that approach seems to work well enough, but that doesn't really help us in the context of the Browsershot library. As far as I know, there's no viable way to get the height of a page within PHP; can anyone think of any potential workarounds on the server side to hack an extremely long screenshot?

I know this isn't really the intended use of the library, and at the end of the day, it's not even the library's limitation, but I thought I'd throw it out there regardless.

Answer (score 1):

With the new contributions to the Spatie's [Browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) you can capture extremely tall web pages with the approach in your provided [example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/230be28b067b521f0577206899db01f0ca7fc0d2/examples/screenshots-longpage.js) easily.

```
$url = 'http://www.spiegel.de';

//Get scrollWidth and scrollHeight of the body in the emulated device
$browsershot = new Browsershot($url, true);
$dimensions = $browsershot
    ->device('iPhone 6')
    ->waitUntilNetworkIdle() // ensuring all additional resources are loaded
    ->evaluate("JSON.stringify({height: document.body.scrollHeight, width: document.body.scrollWidth})");

$dimensions = json_decode($dimensions); 

// iphone 6 scale factor is equal to 2
// https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/DeviceDescriptors.js#L288
$dpr = 2; 
$maxScreenshotHeight = floor(16 * 1024 / $dpr);

for ($ypos = 0; $ypos < $dimensions->height; $ypos += $maxScreenshotHeight) {
    $height = min($dimensions->height - $ypos, $maxScreenshotHeight);
    $browsershot = new Browsershot($url, true);
    $browsershot
        ->device('iPhone 6')
        ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
        ->clip(0, $ypos, $dimensions->width, $height)
        ->timeout(120000) // handling timeout
        ->save('screenshot-@' . $ypos . 'px.png');
}
```